# `await` vs `.then()` : order of execution

Tags: javascript, event-loop, order-of-execution, asynchronous-javascript

I'm trying to understand the order of execution of JavaScript promises. In the following code, `thenFn()` is invoked after `awaitFn()`, but `thenFn()` still executes(complete the task) first. Can someone explain why this happens?

```js
const thenPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Resolved!: then');
    }, 200);
});

const awaitPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Resolved!: await');
    }, 200);
});

async function awaitFn() {
    console.log(await awaitPromise);
}

function thenFn() {
    thenPromise.then((res) => console.log(res));
}

awaitFn();
thenFn();
```

**It is noteworthy that, I declare the `thenPromise` before `awaitPromise`. If I declare `awaitPromise` first I get the expected output.**

Thanks.

***Expected Output:***
Resolved!: await
Resolved!: then

***Actual Output:***
Resolved!: then
Resolved!: await

Comment: `thenPromise` is created first, and thus begins first.  `awaitPromise` is created next, and thus begins next.  Both calls to `setTimeout` have the same delay, so it makes sense that the one which starts first would finish first.  You can swap them by declaring your `new Promise()` instances in the opposite order.  I guess it's not really clear to me why you'd have expected the second one to somehow interrupt the first one...

Comment: @David I think OP expected that using `await` or `.then()` would "start" the promise as if it's a task that is prepared but not executed yet.

Comment: @VLAZ: Ok, that makes sense.  Then for the OP what I'd recommend is to do less assuming and more testing.  Declare the promises by themselves, replace the `resolve` calls with `console.log` calls, never await or do anything with the promises, and observe what happens.

Comment: You don't await on the call to the async function. (you have an await inside the async function but you don't await on the call to the async function)

Comment: First you declare the promises, with a delayed resolve. Then you declare your functions to wait for the promises to resolve. Then you call the functions. The engine doesn't wait for the functions to resolve, but it is put on the task for the event loop. Put a `console.log` inside the body of the timeouts and you see when they fire. If you `await` on the call to the awaitFn you will get the expected result.